# Soluble reactive phosphorus or Dissolved Inorganic Phosphorus?

Tags: water

Why is dissolved inorganic phosphorus called soluble reactive phosphorus (SRP) instead of dissolved inorganic phosphorus (DIP)?

Seems to me that DIP would be much more clear.

See e.g. [General Information on Phosphorus](http://bcn.boulder.co.us/basin/data/NEW/info/TP.html) (City of Boulder/USGS Water Quality Monitoring)

Comment: SRP reflects how the phosphorus is measured in the laboratory: you look which fraction of the dissolved phosphorus compounds is reactive. Commonly, this reactive fraction is the inorganic phosphorus (=> DIP). My information from colleagues, who measure phosphorus compounds in river and marine water, is that one should use the abbreviations DIP, DOP, PIP, and POP (dissolve/particulate inorganic/organic phosphorus) nowadays because the nomenclature is more consistent. However, from the perspective of someone working in the laboratory, SRP describes what is actually measured.